# Trying to wrap this mesh mask to another mesh

Tags: mesh

Beginner here; I'm just trying to figure out how I could get this mask to wrap around and sit on the face, like in the picture below.

I've tried the curve modifier but no joy, also tried the shrink-wrap modifier but that also just went horribly wrong.

I've searched the forum also but maybe I haven't searched the correct terminology so if this has been answered I apologize!

Hoping someone can help:)

[image: mask and face]

Answer (score 3):

You were on the right track when trying to use the Shrink-wrap modifier. All you need to do Is fiddle with some settings.

All you have to make sure is that you select the "Project" mode and tick both of the "Direction" boxes (this tell blender which normal to project, ticking both is just easy). Then you're going to want to increase the offset just a little bit so your projected mesh doesn't intersect too badly with your head.

[image]

I see the mesh you'd like to project looks like its got 3 dimentionality, so if you want to preserve that, I suggest you remake it with splines and add a skin modifier to it.